# RegEx for matching trigrams

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, regex-negation, regex-group

I'm trying to get all groups of three words from a string - which can consist of multiple sentences - without going across sentence boundaries. I've got it working for words that only have standard letters of the alphabet:

```
preg_match_all("/(?=(\b(\w+)(?:\s+(\w+)\b|$)(?:\s+(\w+)\b|$)))/",$utext,$matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

But it falls down where there are apostrophes or hyphens. So, with this sample text:

```
The quick brown fox's feet jumped over the lazy dog. The rain falls head-first in the plain.
```

I want this list:

- The quick brown
- quick brown fox's
- brown fox's feet
- fox's feet jumped
- feet jumped over
- jumped over the
- over the lazy
- the lazy dog
- The rain falls
- rain falls head-first
- falls head-first in
- head-first in the
- in the plain

I've tried using [\w'-] for each \w above, but that gives some oddities:

```
Array ( [0] => The quick brown [1] => quick brown fox's [2] => brown fox's feet [3] => fox's feet jumped [4] => 's feet jumped [5] => s feet jumped [6] => feet jumped over [7] => jumped over the [8] => over the lazy [9] => the lazy dog [10] => The rain falls [11] => rain falls head-first [12] => falls head-first in [13] => head-first in the [14] => -first in the [15] => first in the [16] => in the plain )
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `\w` to `[^\s.]` (not space or dot) and remove the word boudaries. Another change is to add an alternation "beginning of line OR space" at the beginning of the regex:

```
$text = "The quick brown fox's feet jumped over the lazy dog. The rain falls head-first in the plain.";

preg_match_all("/(?=((?<=^|\s)[^\s.]+(?:\s+[^\s.]+|$)(?:\s+[^\s.]+|$)))/",$text,$matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => The quick brown
    [1] => quick brown fox's
    [2] => brown fox's feet
    [3] => fox's feet jumped
    [4] => feet jumped over
    [5] => jumped over the
    [6] => over the lazy
    [7] => the lazy dog
    [8] => The rain falls
    [9] => rain falls head-first
    [10] => falls head-first in
    [11] => head-first in the
    [12] => in the plain
)
```

**Regex explanation:**

```
(?=                     # lookahead
    (                   # start group 1
        (?<=^|\s)       # lookbehind, make sure we have beginning of line or space before
        [^\s.]+         # 1 or more non space, non dot
        (?:             # non capture group
            \s+         # 1 or more spaces
            [^\s.]+     # 1 or more non space, non dot
          |             # OR
            $           # end of line
        )               # end group
        (?:             # non capture group
            \s+         # 1 or more spaces
            [^\s.]+     # 1 or more non space, non dot
          |             # OR
            $           # end of line
        )               # end group
    )                   # end group 1
)                       # end lookahead
```

---

Edit according to comment.

```
$text = "The quick brown fox's feet jumped over the lazy dog. The rain falls head-first in the plain. 'This is a quote,' I say, and that's that.";

preg_match_all("/(?=((?<=^|\s|')(?:(?<=[a-zA-Z])'(?=[a-zA-Z])|[^\s.,'])+(?:\s+(?:(?<=[a-zA-Z])'(?=[a-zA-Z])|[^\s.,'])+|$){2}))/",$text,$matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => The quick brown
    [1] => quick brown fox's
    [2] => brown fox's feet
    [3] => fox's feet jumped
    [4] => s feet jumped
    [5] => feet jumped over
    [6] => jumped over the
    [7] => over the lazy
    [8] => the lazy dog
    [9] => The rain falls
    [10] => rain falls head-first
    [11] => falls head-first in
    [12] => head-first in the
    [13] => in the plain
    [14] => This is a
    [15] => is a quote
    [16] => and that's that
)
```

**Regex explanation:**

```
(?=                             # lookahead
    (                           # start group 1
        (?<=^|\s|')             # lookbehind, make sure we have beginning of line or space or quote before
        (?:                     # start non capture group
            (?<=[a-zA-Z])       # lookbehind, make sure we have a letter before
            '                   # a single quote
            (?=[a-zA-Z])        # lookahead, make sure we have a letter after
          |                     # OR
            [^\s.,']            # not a space or dot or comma or single quote
        )+                      # group may appear 1 or more times
        (?:                     # non capture group
            \s+                 # 1 or more spaces
            (?:                 # non capture group
                (?<=[a-zA-Z])   # lookbehind, make sure we have a letter before
                '               # a single quote
                (?=[a-zA-Z])    # lookahead, make sure we have a letter after
              |                 # OR
                [^\s.,']        # not a space or dot or comma or single quote
            )+                  # group may appear 1 or more times
          |                     # OR
            $                   # end of line
        ){2}                    # end group, must appear twice
    )                           # end group 1
)                               # end lookahead
```

Comment: That's brilliant - thanks. I now see that it struggles with quotes and commas, eg in `'This is a quote,' I say, and that's that.` But I may be asking too much here!

Comment: In that second example, the legitimate trigrams would be: This is a, is a quote, and that's that (because I say is a clause too short to qualify). I guess this is maybe going more into NLP than regex is intended for.

Comment: @thehattery: You can add comma in the character class, but, for the single quote it's a bit more complex because you want to keep quote in `fox's`. Try to replace `[^\s.]+` with `(?:(?<=[a-zA-Z])'(?=[a-zA-Z]|[^\s.,'])+`

Comment: missing ) somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, `(?:(?<=[a-zA-Z])'(?=[a-zA-Z])|[^\s.,'])+`

Comment: That's brilliant - thank you! It only misses `This is a` in the second example, but gets everything else in both examples perfectly.

Comment: @thehattery: Try: `preg_match_all("/(?=((?<=^|\s|')(?:(?<=[a-zA-Z])'(?=[a-zA-Z])|[^\s.,'])+(?:\s+(?:(?<=[a-zA-Z])'(?=[a-zA-Z])|[^\s.,'])+|$){2}))/",$text,$matches);`